# Render a different div on different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get a different div to show for chrome and firefox. I can not get even the div to show up let alone change with each browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much and have a great day.

```js
console.log($.browser.name)
        if($.browser.name == "chrome")
            document.getElementById("chrome").style.display = "block";
        else if($.browser.name == "mozilla")
            document.getElementById("firefox").style.display = "block";
        else
            document.getElementById("other").style.display = "block";
```

```css
#firefox, #chrome, #other {
display: none;
}

#chrome {
background-color: #8dc63f;
border: 2px solid #ffffff;
border-radius:5px;
box-shadow: none;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 25px;
padding: .7rem 2.5rem;
margin-left: 18px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
transition: 350ms ease all;
-webkit-transition: 350ms ease all;
}


#firefox { 
background-color: #8dc63f;
border: 2px solid #ffffff;
border-radius:5px;
box-shadow: none;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 25px;
padding: .7rem 2.5rem;
margin-left: 18px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
transition: 350ms ease all;
-webkit-transition: 350ms ease all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firefox">
<a href="https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/firefox/addon/cape-breton-start-page/">Yes, lets do it</a>
</div>


<div id="chrome">
<a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cape-breton-start-page/gcjbmfbjnmkfnjgdpkamohobejbpdinb/">Yes, lets do it</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as "php"?

Comment: Im sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use something simple as this. I guess that you don't need jQuery, we can use agent string to compare it, see test below

```js
var tst = navigator.userAgent.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') ;
var chr = document.querySelector('.chrome') ;
var fox = document.querySelector('.firefox') ;

( tst > 0 ) ? chr.classList.add('sh') : fox.classList.add('sh')
```

```css
div{ display: none }
div.sh{ display: block }
```

```html
<div class="chrome">I'm shown on Chrome</div>
<div class="firefox">I'm shown on Firefox</div>
```

Comment: How can I add an other to it. I tried but it makes them all chrome. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what 'other' you need to add ? And it works in a way that if you look this webpage in FireFox you'll see it's div, and in Chrome other div..

Comment: If the browser is not Chrome or Firefox i need another div to show and I can make that div say Sorry not available on current browser.